# Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'update' thrown in DJANGO ORM

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I couldn't figure what is wrong with below statement , I am getting 'User' object has no attribute 'update' thrown in DJANGO ORM

```
if "device_id" in request_data:
        try:
            User.objects.get(device_id=request_data["device_id"]).update(device_id=None)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) method used for updating **multiple** objects at one's, where after calling `get` method you have a single instance.
Replace this:

```
User.objects.get(device_id=request_data["device_id"]).update(device_id=None)
```

with this:

```py
user = User.objects.get(device_id=request_data["device_id"])
user.device_id = None
user.save()
```

Or even better would be to allow `device_id` field (which I think is ForeignKey) to be null:

```py
# your model class defenition
...
device = models.ForeignKey('on_device_model', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.deletion.DO_NOTHING)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

update method is of a queryset, when you call get on queryset it return object. so you can update object by set a attribute of object.

you can update object as follow:

```
if "device_id" in request_data:
    try:
       u = User.objects.get(device_id=request_data["device_id"])
       u.device_id=None
       u.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
```