# How to update user details in custom user model in django

Tags: python, django, abstractuser

i just created a custom user model from abstractuser. I can create user but update is not working showing some error. I am also week in english so idk how to share my problem. In short hand i want to edit email and password of a user.

```
###This is my user model

class User(AbstractUser):
    roles =(
       ('Admin','Admin'),
        ('Placement Manager','Placement Manager'),
        )
    username=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True,blank=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices = roles,null=True,blank=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','username','role']

    objects=UserManager()

    def get_username(self):
        return self.email
```

```
 ###This is my view 

def editPlacementManager(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        name=request.POST.get('name')
        phone=request.POST.get('phone')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        userid = request.POST.get('pmId')

        User.objects.get(id=userid).update(username=name,phone=phone,email=email,password=password,role='Placement Manager')
        

        return redirect('listplacementmanager')
    return render(request,"index/placementmanager.html")
```

```
### The error is 

AttributeError at /editplacementmanager
'User' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Comment: I think this will help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67190635/exception-value-user-object-has-no-attribute-update-thrown-in-django-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67190635/exception-value-user-object-has-no-attribute-update-thrown-in-django-orm)

Answer (score 1):

Yh, you'll get that error because the update method is available for only querysets.
So you can do this:

```
def editPlacementManager(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        name=request.POST.get('name')
        phone=request.POST.get('phone')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        userid = request.POST.get('pmId')

        user = User.objects.get(id=userid)
        user.name = name
        user.phone = phone
        user.email = email
        # You can continue with whichever field you want
        user.save()
        # Then finally you save the object with the updated fields
        

        return redirect('listplacementmanager')
    return render(request,"index/placementmanager.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

actually it's a simple thing just hash the password and update.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).